# What regex for a web.config will match part of a URL and allow anything after this text?

Tags: asp.net, regex, redirect, web-config

I'm struggling with completing a regular expression for a web.config file in IIS 7.  We have several hundred pages that will be redirected (per a client request).  Many of these pages have URL patterns that are like this:

- http://site/aaa-bbb/different1.html
- http://site/aaa-bbb/different2.html
- http://site/aaa-bbb/different-again/and-so-on.html

And we intend to redirect these requests to a common page like this:

- http://site/aaa/bbb

There are over a dozen such URL patterns that I need to account for.  So I'm just trying to get this rewrite match to work, rather than applying all of their pages as key-value pairs in the rewrite map.  This is what I have so far, and you can see some of the attempts that I've commented out.

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="301Redirects">
      <add key="/index.htm" value="/" />
      <add key="/index.html" value="/" />
      <add key="/customPage.htm" value="/" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="301 Redirect Rule">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{301Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
<!-- Here is the rule I can't get to work. -->
    <rule name="301 to aaa/bbb" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^/aaa-bbb([\d\w\s])" />
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(.{0,1})" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(.?)" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(.*)$" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(\s\S)" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb[\s\S]*/([\s\S]*?(.htm|.html))" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(.)" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb(.*)" />-->
      <!--<match url="^/aaa-bbb([ _0-9a-z-]+)" />-->
      <action type="Redirect" url="/aaa/bbb" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Now what does work, is if I enter the following URL.

- http://site/aaa-bbb

That will successfully redirect to this:

- http://site/aaa/bbb

But appending anything else at the end of that aaa-bbb winds up generating a 404 error.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: So are you saying you should match `(http://site/aaa)-(bbb/.*)` only to be replaced by `$1/$2` ?

Comment: No, the dash isn't absolute.  The pattern is http://site/CommonString/DifferentStrings.  On the original code that I'm working with, some of the URLs have dashes, so I just left the dash intact when I made the question more generic. Thanks for asking for clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that you started your regexp with `/`. In `<match url=` rewrite module will compare path with out starting slash (Ex: `aaa-bbb/different1.html`) with your regexp. Working example is:

```
<rule name="301 to aaa/bbb" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^aaa-bbb(.?)" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/aaa/bbb" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks Victor, that worked. If I wanted to include that starting slash in the expression, would I need to escape it?

Comment: You don't need to add starting slash, because your regexp will not match.  The pattern will be matched against path starting after the first slash after the domain.
Ex for url: `http://localhost/some/path/in/url` only selected part will be used for matching: `some/path/in/url`